# Play Store: Set age limit

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to set an age limit for applications published on Android store?

There is the "Content rating" in the "Store presence" settings, but the age limit is calculated automatically depending on the questionnaires.

How can I restrict play store to list my app only for users aged >18 years for example, without having to give false answers in the questionnaire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such options in the console and **Content Rating** act as a warning type message to the users. Here are some points of **Content Rating**

- Inform consumers, especially parents, of potentially objectionable
  content within an app.
- Block or filter your content in certain
  territories or to specific users where legally required.
- Evaluate your app’s eligibility for special developer programs.

Answer (score 3):

You can set Primarily Child-Directed option yes and no towards children under the age of 13 as defined by [COPPA](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions#Web) follow these steps

1. Go to the Store presence
2. Select Pricing and distribution and select the Primarily Child-Directed option

But if you select this option you also need to filter the ads if you applied in your app