# Android play store - Change app avaiability age from 3+ to 18+

Tags: android, content-security-policy, mobile-application, google-play-console

I have set my "Target audience" age to 18+ in google play console. But how do I as a user see the age restriction in my app in playstore?

Answer (score 0):

There was a previously asked question, it might help you. [Play Store: Set age limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572863/play-store-set-age-limit)

Also if the user is 18+ he/she is obviously 3+.

Answer (score 0):

Users find the information in PlayStore under 'About this App / More Info' in the form of content ratings. E.g. PEGI 3. There are different ratings for different countries as explained in the help page. The ratings are derived from your answers to the content questionaire for your app in the Pla Console.

(https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6209544?p=appgame_ratings)